# How to copy one field to another and then remove spaces using 1 button in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Ok so I've looked around and tried a few things but nothing I've tried works. Here is what I have. I have one field on my access form where I input a song title. I have another field that needs to have that information copied to it but with hyphens instead of spaces. I'd like to do this either by pressing a button on the form or even in code.

For instance this is what I'd like to happen:
Field 1 = This is a song
Filed 2 is empty

press button on form and then

Field 1 = This is a song
Field 2 = This-is-a-song

I've successfully created a button that copies Field 1 to Field 2 but no luck in removing the spaces. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the **Replace** function in VBA:

```
Field2=Replace(Field1, " ", "-")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Part of my problem was my lack of understanding of how to activate the VBA. However I have figured that out and with your help it worked.  For other newbies this is how I did it. After going into design view I selected the button I wanted to use. I then looked at the property sheet and chose the Event Tab. I selected the on click box and pressed the ... button. I then selected the code builder and put the code above in and it worked.